# Is it possible to use select(2) to watch for SDL text input events?

Tags: c++, select, sdl-2, textinput, event-driven

We have to program a server and a client using event-driven programming - we use [`select(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) to read from stdin and sockets. I'm making an interface for the client using the SDL2 and SDL2_TTF libraries. The problem is I don't know how to make `select(2)` work for SDL text input events, so I cannot connect the client to my interface. How should I do that? Is there a file descriptor I can use to watch my input on the SDL window?

I forgot to mention: we **have** to use `select(2)`

Comment: Could you some code to the question?

Comment: Sure! The _while_ I use for the client is here https://codepaste.net/ukxfdt

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a file descriptor I can use to watch my input on the SDL window?

Nope.  Best you can do is get some platform-specific window handles via [`SDL_GetWindowWMInfo()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowWMInfo) & the [`SDL_SysWMinfo` struct](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SysWMinfo).

You might be able to use [`ConnectionNumber()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29001469/44729) on `x11.display` and `select(2)` on it but that's really X11-specific.

> How should I do that?

Have the main/GUI/SDL thread send messages to your networking thread via `write(2)` on a local socket which the networking thread also `select(2)`s on.  For network thread to main thread communication you can use [`SDL_PushEvent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PushEvent) with a custom event to wake up `SDL_WaitEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

SDL has a polling based event handling so you'll basically want a loop as in

```
while (!quitting) {
 pollEvents();
 drawEverything();
 delayForFPS();
}
```

How to poll for events and how to manage text input events is explained everywhere on SDL tutorials as in [this one](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/32_text_input_and_clipboard_handling/index.php) or [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials/TextInput), but basically it's something like:

```
SDL_Event event;
if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  if (event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT) {
   std::string text = event.text.text;
  }
}
```

So there is no `stdin` or `select` involved at all.

Mind that since you need networking features the above loop may include `pollForPendingPackets()` and `dispatchPackets()` phases which take this into account.

A good approach would be to have the networking thread receive all packets and queue them in a buffer which is then handled by the SDL thread.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the assignment specifically tell us to use select from sys/types.h, so I have to use it

Comment: indeed you will use `select` to manage sockets, not to handle `stdin`.