# XMaskEvent not returning

Tags: x11

I am following this tutorial here: http://www.sbin.org/doc/Xlib/chapt_16.html

Here is the image of the tutorial: [image]

Here is my code: (it is in another thread from which I called `XInitThreads` - I know using threads and X is bad, I know I should be on the main thread, but just wondering if possible)

```
            var ev = XEvent();

            var rez_XMaskEvent = XMaskEvent(cachedXOpenDisplay(), ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask, ev.address());
            console.log('rez_XMaskEvent:', rez_XMaskEvent);

            console.log('ev:', ev);
```

- `ButtonPressMask` is `4`
- `ButtonReleaseMask` is `8`

So `XMaskEvent` is blocking, but whenever I press my mouse button it is not catching it. Shouldn't it unblock and get to the `console.log` line?

Do I need to run an event loop somehow in this thread?

Thanks

Comment: What language is this? Clearly not C/C++...

Comment: Thanks @Jvo for attenion. Its js-ctypes, but i tried to make this question language agnostic.

Comment: Have you called XSelectInput?

Comment: Thanks @n.m. yes but I had to give up on that method because it doesn't allow me to block the pointer events, it is awesome to asynchronously monitor the events though. The reason I can't block is because `XGrabPointer` is not working for me and I can't explain it after weeks of experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure here but I feel this could be your problem:

You probably can't do this from JavaScript without some extra precautions. JavaScript in the browser is single-threaded. That means you're holding a lock and no other JavaScript can run. Your problem is a) you're using threads and b) "If the event you requested is not in the queue, XMaskEvent flushes the output buffer and blocks until one is received." ([see the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xmaskevent))

That means `XMaskEvent` blocks since the button hasn't been pressed, yet. And your browser can't execute JavaScript anymore. If there is an event in the queue which would trigger some JavaScript, the browser will lock up.

Comment: Thanks very much Aaron, you're the only one I get replies from haha. Yep js is single threaded, however if we spawn it in a WebWorker, the worker is a thread. So in its own thread. So the javascript is executing for sure. I got it work from the thread for Windows, and Mac OS X. Just need to do something for linux/bsd :(  This is my linux code: https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl/blob/master/modules/workers/MMSyncWorker.js#L891-L907 around it you see the windows and os x code, they also are similiar technique. I set up a callback, then I run an event loop which is blocking.

Comment: As The event is received it breaks, the callback runs, and the loop continues. Is there anyway to make the thread get the message. Using `XSelectInput` works, but I can't succesfully do `XGrabPointer` so I can't block the calls. So that's why I'm now investigating `XMaskEvent` :(

Comment: You said, it never gets to the second `console.log()` and now you say it does. Which one is correct?

Comment: Oh excuse that please. Yep it does not get to the console.log because it is blocking the `XMaskEvent` call is blocking.

Comment: Can you prove that you don't run in a deadlock?

Comment: Thanks so much Aaron Im stumped on this. How would I prove its not deadlock? `XMaskEvent` is blocking (as expected), but when I press a button my mouse it is not unblocking :(

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in the JavaScript engine or the browser's event loop? I'm pretty convinced that you get some event which the browser can't process because your code is holding a lock (maybe just by being executed). Can you add a JavaScript event handler to the page to see whether it still triggers after calling `XMaskEvent`?

Comment: I just tested. I ran my code, so it got to `XMaskEvent` and got stuck. Now while its stuck, I downloaded and installed another one of my addons that uses x11:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ and then i clicked take screenshot, this code uses x11 to take a screenshot and it worked fine this is the x11 code: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/workers/MainWorker.js#L1316-L1421 - all the while, the `XMaskEvent` is still blocking. Weird huh? This shows its not holding lock huh? Thanks so much working on me with this, this is just free open source

Comment: Oh wow I just did XNextEvent and it also is blocking infinitely. I only got XNextEvent to work in past when I did `XCreateSimpleWindow`, `XSelectInput`, `XMapWindow`, `XFlush`, then `XNextEvent` works. So weird.

Comment: Wow this is so weird. I can only get `XMaskEvent` to return, if I create simple window and then `XSelectInput` to that window. Then clicking only in that window, makes the `XMaskEvent` unblock. Is there anyway to `XSelectInput` on root? Should I have to be doing `XSelectInput`? I tried `XSelectInput` on the root window but it crashes instantly.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to do what `gdk_window_add_filter` does when argument of window is passed as null - https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-add-filter - they have to be doing it with x11 no? i found this source but cant find the X calls its making: https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/gdkwindow_8c_source.html#l00115

Comment: I tried to also pass to `XSelectInput` the XID of my existing window, the `XSelectInput` succeeds, however doing the `XMaskEvent` call after it crashes it. Even doing a `XFlush` after the `XSelectInput` crashes it. :(

Comment: Are you calling `XMaskEvent` on a window which you created or did Firefox create it? In the latter case, I would assume that there is a main loop running somewhere which eats your events. `gdk_window_add_filter ` works since it adds the filters to the GDK main loop. That means the framework synchronizes everything properly. If you add a second event loop to a window **and** you don't block the first one, it's probably pure chance who will get which event if you run both loops in different threads.

Comment: Ah gosh ok I think I won't be able to keep things consistent with osx and windows - it looks like I'll have to have to do this from the main thread huh?