# Making a blocking call asynchronous

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm using Crystal [bindings for X11](https://github.com/TamasSzekeres/x11-cr/) and typical usage [looks something like this](https://github.com/TamasSzekeres/x11-cr/blob/master/examples/sample_window_hl/src/sample_window_hl.cr):

```
loop do
    event = display.next_event # <- blocking!
    # do stuff with event
end
```

This works fine but I can't do anything in parallel now because `next_event` is native C code and thus never yields.

xlib's NextEvent is always blocking, also in C. There's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592292) about it with possible alternatives, but polling is slower and more CPU demanding than `next_event`, so I'd like to stick to that blocking call. Do I have to put this into its separate OS thread? `-Dpreview_mt` actually solves this, but that's an experimental flag and makes *all* concurrency threaded which is unnecessary (edit: Just found out, this is not true, there is `spawn same_thread: true do` syntax). What options do I have?

Edit: I just found this is discussed in more detail in [this thread](https://forum.crystal-lang.org/t/fibers-blocking-io-and-c-libraries/3116/12) which is worth reading on the topic. There's also `FileDescriptor`'s `wait_readable` which can resolve this if you can obtain a FD somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a lib function blocks, you can't do anything about it in Crystal. You will need to run it in a separate OS thread in order to be able to run other code in parallel. That's what such methods are designed to be used for.

In Crystal, you don't need `preview_mt` to just run a separate OS thread. This flag enables multithreaded scheduling for the Crystal runtime. For your use case, you actually just need a dedicated thread to wait for a blocking call to finish.
The thread API is not publicly exposed, but you can use `Thread.new { }` to create a new OS thread and run the proc in that thread.

I think we'll need to add a public API for such use cases to the language. But currently, it's not documented (so it might be subject to change, but that's unlikely).

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense! In my case, I also want to communicate with the thread (Channels), so I guess it does have to be `preview_mt` anyway.

Comment: Well you can't really do that when the thread is blocking. That's the whole point. Channels are useful for sending messages within non-blocking concurrency.
In other words: You don't need channels to communicate with your blocking thread.

Comment: sorry, I was being a bit indistinct here. I meant to say: As far as I understand now, for `display.next_event` Channels are useless, but on top of that I'm [also employing a third GUI thread](https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11/blob/e90e4cd30cf23893405a643a2a0391596e4f4a23/src/run/gui.cr) which is blocking only *99% of the time* (`LibGtk.main`), and when it's not (requested with `Glib.idle_add`), I want to communicate with it (`msgbox`), so I think this is the only way. At least it now works as expected - with `Thread.new` alone the Channel did not work.

Comment: Note there is also an issue about this on GitHub. My comment there https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/11778#issuecomment-1193197288 has a code example for how to run a blocking call in a separate thread. It serves as an adapter into Crystal's scheduler. Works without `preview_mt`.

Comment: oh, cool stuff! I tried building it like that and it works great so far, this can indeed fix/replace cross-thread channels without preview_mt. However, the workaround eats a lot of cpu when the task takes a long time, because `Fiber.yield` fires over and over again, specially when there are multiple instances of `run_blocking` running. I added a small sleep delay into the loop and it's okay now. Thanks.